# Unable to extend my dual-boot Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, resize

I have a Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual-boot; I am trying to extend my Ubuntu partition with approximately 20 more GB from the /sda3 disk (my D: disk on Windows) using GParted from a live USB. /sda4 is my Ubuntu partition. I have tried resizing etc. but apparently I am not able to extend /sda4 or /sda5. How could I go about this? Is there any way to extend my Linux partition or would I have to delete everything and install Ubuntu again? Side-note: if I press "New" I get an error message saying "It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions".

[Screenshot from GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iacYR.png)

Comment: The real problem is that you've got to remove stuff from your sda2 and sda3 partitions. You disk is too full. Doing what you ask is possible, but complicated. First you should have good backups. Briefly... shrink sda3 from Windows using Window's own Disk Management app. Then boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Unmount sda6 swap. Extend sda4 to the left. Move sda5 left. Extend sda5 right.

Answer (score 0):

We could shrink a partition either form left or the right, but if we are to merge that unallocated space to another partition, unallocated space need to be on the right side.

- As you use MBR partition scheme, you can't have more than 4 primary
  partitions.
- As `/dev/sda4` is the right most primary partition, there
  isn't much you could do. ([LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) addresses such matters though)

That's why it is recommended to have a separate `/home` partition in case you want to reinstall.

**Note:**

- You should not use Window's Disk Management tool to shrink/create
  partitions, as it could convert it to a dynamic disk.

Comment: I understand. So do I delete /sda4 and install Ubuntu all over again?

Comment: No wait. There is still more answers to come :)

Comment: Technically there's no such thing as merge. You can shrink/extend partitions from the left or right... but I prefer to do it from the right, so you move/extend the partition. LVM and a separate /home have nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @heynnema see the updated post. if he had a separate /home he could have fixed that easily. but now he can't. it is just a suggestion.

Comment: You SHOULD use Window's Disk Management app to resize the NTFS partition, and use Gparted to move/resize the ext4 partition.